# "WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available." Ubuntu 21.04 Python 3.8.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, pip

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 that comes with Python 3.9.4 but I needed to create a virtual environment with 3.8.

I manually installed 3.8.10 with this guide: https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/ and created a venv with `python3.8 -m venv NAME`. I activate it, the Python and Pip version are correct.

Problem is when I go and try installing wheel I get this error: `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

I don't get the same error if I use the system python version to create a venv.

I checked the (many) other questions related to this but most of them are for windows or mac or a remote installation, I'm on a local machine.

Comment: this might happen if you built Python from source, and `libssl-dev` wasn't installed on your machine. Can you check the output of `dpkg -s libssl-dev`?

Comment: That was the issue, I reran the config and install after installing ssl and now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libssl-dev` is required to build the `ssl` module from source.

If you install Python from the package repositories, you will be installing a pre-built binary, so you won't need the openssl development files on your own machine, because these files are sort of 'baked-in' to the release.

But if you build Python from source yourself, you will need to install the `libssl-dev` (openssl development files) package in order to build Python with the `ssl` module.

You can check whether you have `libssl-dev` installed by looking at the output of:

```
dpkg -s libssl-dev
```

If it is not installed, you can install it with (may require privileges e.g. `sudo`):

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

If you then rebuild Python from source the `ssl` module should be available.

NOTE: There are other dependencies too which might be missing and result in a less than fully-functional Python installation. Pay attention to the output you get when building. A (maybe incomplete) list of these dependencies' names in the Ubuntu repositories is: `libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev`

Comment: +100 on this answer

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question as the OP is not compiling python from source.

Comment: @JasonGabler the link OP gives is about how to compile alternate versions of Python from source.

Comment: @L.Grozinger thanks.  You are correct. Weird, I must've misread the post. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling python fixed it for me.

```
pyenv install v3.8

>
pyenv: /home/gabi/.pyenv/versions/3.x.x already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
...
```